# conditionally show div on $route path change not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue. I am trying to conditionally show an element based off the router link. If the link is in '/' or home I want to show it, if moving to any other link I'd like to hide it. I tried to use watch to check for changes within the $route path however I get an error that it can't recognise this.$route. I want to trigger a variable for change the condition through v-if and v-else. This is in my app.js file. Thank you.

Error I receive - App.vue?3dfd:89 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$route.path is not a function
at Proxy.$route (App.vue?3dfd:89)

```
    <template>
   <div class="container">
      <section class="projects">
         <div class="toggleBtn">
            <p v-if='home'>
               <router-link to="/">projects</router-link> /
               <router-link to="/experiments">experiments</router-link>
            </p>
             <p v-else>
               <router-link class="back" to="/">BACK TO PROJECTS</router-link>
            </p>
         </div>
         <router-view />
      </section>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      data() {
         return {
            home: true
         }
      },
      mounted() {
         this.animateTitle()
      },
      watch: {
         $route(to, from) {
            if (this.$route.path("/") || this.$route.path("/home")) {
               this.home = true
            } else {
               this.home = false
            }
         }
      },
      methods: {
         animateTitle() {}}


</script>

<style>


   .toggleBtn {
      position: relative;
      width: 15vw;
      margin-left: 78vw;
      margin-top: 90vh;
      border-radius: 20px;
      z-index: 3;
   }

   .toggleBtn p {
      font-family: 'Fantasque Italic';
      line-height: 1;
      white-space: nowrap;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
   }

   .toggleBtn a {
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 20px;
      color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
   }

   .toggleBtn a:hover {
      text-decoration: line-through;
   }

   .toggleBtn a.router-link-exact-active {
       color: black;
   }

   .back {
      color: black;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: The error seems very clear to me - `this.$route.path is not a function` - because [it is a string](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#path-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

A better answer as Maavia suggested should look like this:

Add a computed property

```
computed: {
isHome() {
    return this.$route.path == "/" ||  this.$route.path == "/home";
   }
}
```

Then Check for its value in the template:

```
    <p v-if='isHome'>
       <router-link to="/">projects</router-link> /
       <router-link to="/experiments">experiments</router-link>
    </p>
```

Check out the if statement.

```
watch: {
     $route(to, from) {
        if (this.$route.path == "/" || this.$route.path == "/home" ) {
           this.home = true
        } else {
           this.home = false
        }
     }
  },
```

Comment: there are many ways to do but your sort of method is not for this type of problem.
it can be used for different type of probelm

Comment: I agree, your method method is cleaner. My answer was just to resolve the issue Laiqa was running into.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a compute method for that and place check on compute method

```
computed: {
currentRouteName() {
    return this.$route.name;
   }
}
```

you can simply check on div

Comment: Or in this case the path. this.$route.path